# VS2013 - MVC app - Seed DB when in Debug Config Only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seed

I have an ASP.NET MVC app using code-first. I have an initalizer that seeds the DB. How can I make sure that the initializer only seeds the DB when in Debug config?

This is my first attempt at code-first, so what will happen to existing data when I deploy the site to release? I need to make sure it doesn't delete any data.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: I usually use a local variable or a compiler directive (#IF DEBUG...) To change the connection string / setup steps for the debug mode.

Comment: You shouldn't be running `update-database` against a production database, anyways.

Comment: @Origin thanks. That should do it. My web config automatically changes connection string based on config (I forget what the features called, but it's basically XSL)

Comment: @ChrisPratt How on earth do I update the schema then. The whole point of code first is to have the app update the schema automatically. We've worked with schema and app updates independently for years and it's a pain

Comment: No, the whole point of code first is to give you a frictionless development environment. It is not, and was never, meant to replace production depliyment best practices. You can generate SQL scripts from your migrations to deploy to production with. Or, you can use the rather powerful SQL Server data-tier applications.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - thanks Chris. Guess we'll stick with Redgate for deploying DB changes then